# Not able to read BigDecimal property in java getter method

Tags: java, getter, bigdecimal

I am having a property discount=30 in properties file and 
declaring it as below in jave file :

```
private BigDecimal discount;
public void setDiscount(BigDecimal discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}
public BigDecimal getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}
```

getDiscount() is returning NULL when i try to get its value .
But I need it as BigDecimal only .
I dont have to declare it as String or double and type cast it though that will work.
Using String or double is working fine except for Big Decimal.
Please help me to fix this or what is the reason BigDecimal is not working in this case ?

Comment: The problem is not with BigDecimal. It is where how you set and get it. Please post your code where you set it

Comment: It is probably null because it is not being set in the first place. It looks like you are missing something that knows how to convert your String "30" from the properties file in a BigDecimal. Are you using Spring? Or ...?

Comment: I am declaring the value in ATG properties file and trying to access in a java file.

Comment: properties file(config.properties) : discount=30                                                                                 java file(config.java) :                                                     private BigDecimal discount;
public void setDiscount(BigDecimal discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}
public BigDecimal getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}                                                                       And i am using it as BigDecimal discountPercentage = getconfig().getDiscount(); in calculator.java

Answer (score 0):

It think it will work fine, but if it returns `null` you didnt set it before calling the getter. If you are not able to ensure that the value is set before calling the getter, you can instantiat it in the class. for example with 0.

```
private BigDecimal discount = new BigDecimal(0);
```

and if you call the setter you have to do convert the value you would pass to an long or double and then use `BigDecimal.valueOf()`.

Comment: well it could be an entity, or he could just not post the whole code. Wait until more information is provided :)

Answer (score 0):

In Properties files its always returned as String.

While getting the data from properties file convert it into BigDecimal then use it.

```
SelectClient c= new SelectClient();
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(prop.getProperty("data"));
c.setDiscount(b);
System.out.println(c.getDiscount());
```